# Replacing variable value based on dictionary/list imported from csv

Tags: python, dictionary, replace

I read all the documentation but I am just not getting it.

Here's what I am trying to do:

Replace a string value stored in a variable by another value based on a dictionary list

e.g. Variable contains 'This is my original string' to be replaced by 'This is my replaced string'. There may be about 500 strings in this dictionary.

Here's the approach I tried so far:

Imported csv into a Dataframe which has a dictionary of current value and value to be replaced by

Converted Dataframe into a Dictionary using to_dict()

In a for loop for the dictionary items - tried replace() command for the variable value

Keeps giving me error. I am sure I am doing something foundationally wrong or I just haven't understood the usage rules.

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: _run_module_as_main)
replace() argument 2 must be str, not Series
  File "C:\python\Scripts\BW_Translate.py", line 60, in <module>
    AcctName = AcctName.replace(key,value)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```
tran_csv = 'X:/00XYZZZZ-FIN/acct_translation.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(tran_csv)
print('dictionary:' + df.to_string())

tran_dict = df.to_dict('list')

for f in xml_file_list:
    print('reading:' + f)
    tree = ET.parse(f)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for coding in root.findall('.//CodingRows/CodingRow'):
        AcctName = coding.find('AccountName').text
        for key,value in df.items():
            AcctName = AcctName.replace(key,value)
```

Comment: The error is saying to use `.replace('actual_value', 'new_value')` correct datatypes, i.e., string, where you are using `key, value` which is not a string, it(value) is a `Series`

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the fact that you are trying to use the `replace()` method on a string with a Series as the second argument, which is not allowed. The `replace()` method expects both arguments to be strings, but you are passing a dictionary of values obtained from your DataFrame, which results in Series objects.

You can modify your code to the following to get it to work:

```py
import pandas as pd

tran_csv = 'X:/00XYZZZZ-FIN/acct_translation.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(tran_csv)

tran_dict = dict(zip(df['Current'], df['Replacement']))

for f in xml_file_list:
    print('reading:' + f)
    tree = ET.parse(f)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for coding in root.findall('.//CodingRows/CodingRow'):
        AcctName = coding.find('AccountName').text
        for current_value, replacement_value in tran_dict.items():
            AcctName = AcctName.replace(current_value, replacement_value)
```

In this code, we create a dictionary `tran_dict` with the "Current" values from your DataFrame as keys and the corresponding "Replacement" values as values. During the iteration over your XML data, we use `AcctName.replace(current_value, replacement_value)` to perform the string replacement for each pair of values in the `tran_dict` dictionary.